# Updating deep level child node

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database, and querying a child node from a HTTPS-triggered cloud function.  Is there a way to save the path of that node?

We cannot use wild-card path in this function - are there any available functions I can use, or any other solution that will help?

Firebase Realtime Database structure looks like:

```
colleges: 
   clg1:
     departments:
           dep1:
             students:
               stu1:
                  name:
                  phone:
               stu2:
                  name:
                  phone:
            dep2:
              students:
                stu3:
                  name:
                  phone:
    clg2:
     departments:
           dep3:
             students:
               stu4:
                  name:
                  phone:
               stu5:
                  name:
                  phone:
            dep4:
              students:
                stu6:
                  name:
                  phone:
```

Here, I want to update phone of specific student; how should I do it, given that we cannot make use of wildcard path in https cloud function?

Answer (score 0):

You can access and save values to students:

set:

```
admin.database().ref(`departments/${dptid}/students/${sudentid}`).set({data:1})
```

update:

```
admin.database().ref(`departments/${dptid}/students/${sudentid}`).update({data:1})
```

Comment: but we cannot make use of wildcard path in https cloud function since i am gonna write my code in https cloud function